# LINQ Replacement for Nested Array Iteration and Update?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I need some help with syntactic sugar.
I have a ThisClass[3] and ThatClass[3].

```
public class ThisClass
{
    public string Thing1;
    public string Thing2;
    public string Thing3;
    public string Thing4;
}

public class ThatClass
{
    public string Thing1;
    public string Thing2;
}
```

Each instance in the array of ThatClass was created based on an instance in the same position of array ThisClass.
So ThatClass[0] has its fields with the same values as ThisClass[0], except it only has 2 fields instead of 4.

I would like to now update each instance in the ThisClass array, with fields from the matching index position of the object in the ThatClass array. I could do nested for loops, but I need help thinking through a LINQ option.

```
 ThisClass[0].Thing1 = ThatClass[0].Thing1; 
 ThisClass[0].Thing2 =  ThatClass[0].Thing2;
```

works but I am sure could be done better. Using C#, .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see any need for *nested* loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < theseClasses.Length; i++)
{
    theseClasses[i].Thing1 = thoseClasses[i].Thing1;
    theseClasses[i].Thing2 = thoseClasses[i].Thing2;
}
```

You could potentially add a `CopyFrom(ThatClass)` method to `ThisClass`, leading to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < theseClasses.Length; i++)
{
    theseClasses[i].CopyFrom(thoseClasses[i]);
}
```

... but that's all I'd do. LINQ is do to with *querying*, not causing side-effects... I don't think it's a good fit here.

Answer (score 1):

*Attention*: As @Jon put, LINQ is not about causing side-effects and if you do so you may end up with a code with unexpected behavior (but it's possible).

This code does that:

```
ThisClass[] these = new ThisClass[100];
ThatClass[] those = new ThatClass[100];

// init these and those items

those.Zip(these, (that, @this) =>
{
    @this.Thing1 = that.Thing1;
    @this.Thing2 = that.Thing2;
    return that;
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

As you're asking for LINQ... this will get you an **unrelated** `IEnumerable<ThisClass>,` and will not modify the original array.
(I'm assuming that the `thisClass` and `thatClass` arrays are called `thisArray` and `thatArray`, respectively)

```
thisArray.Select((n, x) => { n.Thing1 = thatArray[x].Thing1; n.Thing2 = thatArray[x].Thing2; return n; }).ToArray();
```

(If you really wanted LINQ and assigning it, just assign it back to the original array)

Comment: @Downvoter, What. Is. The. Problem? He asked for **LINQ**, I gave **LINQ**. I DID mention it would not modify the original one, and it DOES work. I've tested it. What is the problem?

Comment: Your code won't work, because `Select()` is lazy. So, if you do this, nothing will actually happen. That's one reason why using LINQ to do this is a bad idea.

Comment: @svick Fixed that, my overlook.